# How to put an angle on a specific point?

Tags: angle, pst-eucl

I would like to, for example, make an triangle with one angle of 50 degrees and the adjacent segments of 4cm, so I can do that with the following code:

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,5)
\pstTriangle(0,0){a}(4;50){b}(4,0){c}
\end{pspicture}
```

But how can I do that if i want the triangle to start on point (1,0) for example?
The following code will cause the BÂC angle (witch I want to have 50 degrees) to have more than 50 degrees, and the segment AC to have 3cm instead of 4cm, because the angle will be on (0,0) and not on (1,0) where the point A is!

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,5)
\pstTriangle(1,0){a}(4;50){b}(4,0){c}
\end{pspicture}
```

So how can I make the angle be on the right place?
I hope I was clear!

Comment: Can you extend your examples to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: @Luca, any chance for an MWE?